# Ordered logit and proportional odds assumption

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

According to Wikipedia, ordered logit regression relies on the proportional odds assumption.

Suppose that the proportion of people in groups 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are given by p1, p2, p3, p4, and p5.

Denote
$$
\Delta := \log \frac{p1 + p2}{p3 + p4 + p5} - \log \frac{p1}{p2 + p3 + p4 + p5}.
$$

My understanding of the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit#cite_note-2) is that under the proportional odds assumption:
$$
\log \frac{p1 + p2 + p3}{p4 + p5} - \log \frac{p1 + p2}{p3 + p4 + p5} = \Delta
$$
and
$$
\log \frac{p1 + p2 + p3 + p4}{p5} - \log \frac{p1 + p2 + p3}{p4 + p5} = \Delta
$$
must hold.

Is my interpretation correct?

If it is, then the proportional odds assumption is too restrictive and probably not useful. The above implies that the distance between the parallel lines in the linear regression is separated by $\Delta$. But I don't understnad why it needs to be separated by $\Delta$. Why is this required?